# Namespace does not resolve correctly

Tags: php, namespaces, php-7.4

[image]The namespace system, even aft a redraft of the Classmap in composer.json, and a dump-autoload, has given me not objects in the named spaces. This seems to be escalating as well. Whereas I have one file that does this, it is with finite progress becoming a larger problem. I don't know what to do. Here is one of the code files that are not operating.

This is login.php:

```
<?php
namespace Adoms\crud;

require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = false;
}
?>
    <?php

        if (!isset($_GET['g'])) {
            require('view/login/username.php');
        }
        else if (isset($_GET['g']) && $_GET['g'] == 1) {
            require('view/login/pass.php');
        }
        else {
            $login = new db("../Adoms/config/config.json");   // Says no "Adoms\crud\db" in error msg

            $record = $login->read(["users" => ["site_id", "username"]], "username = '" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "' AND password = '" . $_COOKIE['password'] . "'");

            if ($record->num_rows == 1) {
                header("Location: ../");
            }

        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have your file autoloaded you need to use files in composer.json autoload and just add your file path then dump-autoload and should load up.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "path/to/yourfile.php",

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when dealing with such a problem, you may wish to update your composer.lock. This is by using `composer update` at the console. This should solve anyone's problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the above answer does not work, this should fix it. Put the first object's namespace first. This here means, that `crud` goes before `oauth`

```
    namespace Adoms\crud;

    use Adoms\src\oauth2;
    include_once("../../../vendor/autoload.php");

    if (!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    $db = new db("../../../Adoms/config/config.json");

    $result = $db->read(["users" => ["username", "site_id"]], "`site_id` = '" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "' OR `username` = \"" . $_POST['username'] . "\"");
?>
```